# Resizing Textbox/textarea to fit text

Tags: asp.net, html, webforms

I need to create user control with Texbox Textmode="Multiline" or html textarea.

When in edit mode Textbox/textarea has to be resizable. I can use some jquery plugin for this. But in read only mode this Textbox/textarea is disabled and it must be automatically resized (height) to fit the text. Even if text takes pages. I could just hide Textbox/textarea in read only mode and display text in div but I would like to keep edit and readonly page look same.

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't know if this will help you or not but [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/textarea-tricks/) has something. See number 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why have textarea/input in readonly mode - versus using js to switch back and forth between that control and a DIV or a P tag (to display the text), where simply by not setting the height (or setting it to `height:auto`) that box would automatically size to contain all text?

Also, unless your surrounding content doesn't allow that, enable resizing the textarea to the user; see http://davidwalsh.name/textarea-resize

Comment: I don't like it because it makes page look different in edit/readonly modes. Other screens look same in those two modes so I'd rather stick to that with that new screen. But if I would do it I would show/hide controls on server side. Doing it in JS sometimes makes controls appear and then dissapear after some time.

Comment: You can border a DIV and make it look exactly like your textarea (or vice-versa). I can't agree that POST to the server is a better solution over a POSSIBLE JS/DHTML-flicker (in this case, I doubt there would be any), as POST would delay the show/hide process even more (plus you have unnecessary server trip and the server rebuilding the page, then the app hitting the database and the session store, and what-not, all w/o a real need).

Comment: Besides, the only proper way to achieve what you want would be to create an invisible DIV, set its width, margin, padding, border, font-family, font-size (did I miss anything) to be the same as in textarea, add text to it, and THEN measure its height, and THEN set that height to the textarea, and then finally remove the temp DIV. The same approach is used to truncate (ellipsis) text, for example. So, you have a DIV anyway. So, I guess, I just gave away another way to do what you want :)

Comment: You didn't understand me. I am not posting to server to change textarea into div. I have usercontrol that is used on two pages. On one it displays in edit mode. On other in readonly mode. So I decide in Page_Load to show either textarea or div. And that's what I did. I replace textarea with div in readonly mode.